# How can I setup steps in spring batch to process a progressive set of inputs?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a set of 7 api's which I need to query in sequence, process the input, and write the results to a csv. The api is laid out as follows:

```
http://api.com/bar/list         //Returns a map of 'bar names' -> 'barid's'.
http://api.com/bar/barid        //Returns details of a bar (id from previous api).
http://api.com/foo/barid/list   //Returns a map of 'foo names' -> 'fooid's'.
http://api.com/foo/barid/fooid  //Returns details of a foo.
http://api.com/baz/barid/list   //Returns a map of 'baz names' -> 'bazid's'.
http://api.com/baz/barid/bazid  //Returns details of a baz.
http://api.com/foz/barid/list   //A request which also takes foo id's and baz id's as post parameters.
```

I'm having real difficulty finding a spring batch example which deals with an case like the one above. In most examples I can find, there is one input, one output and any number of processors. The only examples I have found which deal with multiple inputs are reading from relational databases and recommend joining the required tables to form a single input..

I assume it must be possible to setup multiple input steps together in the way I want, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction or provide a little example so I can set it up. It's also possible that I'm thinking about the problem all wrong, so please tell me if that's the case, I'm new to batch so might be missing something really obvious.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Just thought, I should probably mention that the final API returns a large amount of data, so ideally I would want to process one bar at a time to avoid memory issues.

Comment: Does the bar/list api support any type of paging?

Comment: Unfortunately not, however the full results can be held in memory for the bar/list api, it's 500kB at the most (and that's an overestimate). It's the last api which is really expensive.. All the others could probably be held in memory simultaneously.